# Hibernate - automatically delete children when updating parent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two tables. `Site` have a lot of `Sector`s.

When I try to edit the list of sectors of a site, for example I have 3 sectors initially, so I delete one sector and I update the site. in the database are three sectors of the Site.

Is it possible that the sectors are automatically deleted when I update a site? or I have to compare one to one?

Thanks.

Site entity

```
public class Site {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    ....

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "site", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)    
    private List<Sector> sectores;
}
```

Sector entity

```
public class Sector {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="idGenerator", sequenceName="SECTOR_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "IDSECT")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDSITE")
    private Site site;
}
```

log

```
08:17:55,096 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Hibernate: update SITE set SITIO_CODIGO=?, SITIO_NOMBRE=? where ID=?

08:17:55,116 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Hibernate: update SECTOR set NOMBRE=?, IDSITIO=? where IDSECT=?
```

Comment: as per my understanding, it should remove the entry from the sector table once you update the site object. just make sure that the list present inside the site object has now only 2 elements instead of 3.

Comment: The list contains two elements, then I update the site. 
When I go back to check, the 3 elements appear again.

Comment: mappedBy = "sitio" might be an issue...i think it should be mappedBy = "site"

Comment: It is a problem of translation, and I corrected. When I change some value of the sectors are updated, but when I remove an item from the list and then update the site, is still listed as his child.

Comment: FetchType.EAGER is sometimes an issue as also encountered here https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1004627

Comment: I changed for Site: @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy="site", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    and for Sector  @JoinColumn(name = "IDSITIO")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @ForeignKey(name = "IDSITIO") but the problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you got it yet, but maybe the @GeneratedValue is a problem for it is different from the Sites' @GeneratedValue

but if that is not the case then maybe change

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "site", cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

To

```
@OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy="mcrPosTran")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

And change in the sector

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDSITE")
private Site site;
```

To

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "IDSITE")
private Site site;
```